# Database schema for posts with multiple tags

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, database-schema

I am building the typical post and tag application where a post can have multiple tags.  I am stuck on setting up the database schema.  I have so far:

Post:
POST_ID PRIMARY KEY 
    POST_TITLE 
    POST_BODY
    POST_DATE
    POST_USERID

Tag:
TAG_ID PRIMARY KEY
    TAG_TAGNAME

PT:
PT_ID 
PT_POSTID 
PT_TAGID

When a user submits a post, I insert the form data into the post table. Next step I loop through the tagnames the user provided and see if they are in the TAG_TAGNAME field.  If there is a match,  grab the ID and insert it into the PT table. ELSE insert the name into the tag table and grab the ID and insert it into the PT table.Both are along with the postid generated in the POST table insert. 

Finally I have a view called PTVIEW with the following schema:

SELECT *
FROM dbo.PT
JOIN Post
ON PT_PostID = dbo.Post.POST_ID
JOIN Tag
ON PT_TagID = tag.TAG_ID

Here is a sample result of select * from PTVIEW
[image]

Problem is I can’t get a  view of the unique posts along with their tags. 
I am using MSSQL so I DO NOT have the Group_concat function built into mySQL.

I can’t build the initial page that will show each post along with its correlating tags like stackoverflow does on the homepage.  What am I doing wrong in the PTVIEW ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically have 2 options:

1. Split it up into 2 different queries, get a post, then get it's
   associated tags.
2. Concatenate the tags into a single field using a statement like
   this:

> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT
>         P.Post_ID ,
>         SUBSTRING(( SELECT  ',' + T.TAG_TAGNAME AS [text()]
>                     FROM    dbo.PT PT
>                             INNER JOIN dbo.Tag T ON PT.PT_TAGID = T.TAG_ID
>                     WHERE   P.POST_ID = PT.POST_ID
>                   FOR
>                     XML PATH('')
>                   ), 2, 1000) [Tags]
> FROM    dbo.Post P
> ```

Even though the second option looks kinda nifty, the first option has my personal preference. 
I think the second is not very readable and performance would not be very good on larger datasets.

Comment: If I use the first option, the only way I can think of listing the top # of posts and their tags is to use a nested loop. Grabbing each postID and then another select to get the tagnames.  Am I wrong? I feel like this would also be quite a load on the server if there are lots of posts.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I learned to do it.

```
  SELECT * 
    ,(
        SELECT TAG_TAGNAME+ ', '
        from PT
        JOIN Tag ON PT_TagID = TAG_ID
        Where PT_PostID = POST_ID
        ORDER BY TAG_TAGNAME
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ) AS Tags
    FROM Post
```